# How to access wxmenuitem created in GUIFrame.cpp

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I'm new to C++, so please bear with me.
I've created a function at the end on my Main.cpp file, and whenever I try calling something inside GUIFrame.h, it works fine. But if it wasn't declared in GUIFrame.h and instead in GUIFrame.cpp, it tells me "error: 'Mywxmenuitem' was not declared in this scope."

Since I'm not supposed to edit the GUIFrame.h/GUIFrame.cpp pages, how do I access my elements created in GUIFrame.cpp? I just want to set/get the checked property of some wxmenuitems...

Comment: Are you using a GUI editor for creating your GUIFrame.cpp/.h files? If not then could you explaing why you are not supposed to edit these files? If you are going to add the menu event handler, you need to declare it inside the declaration of your frame class (in .h file) and then implement in a corresponding .cpp file. After that you need to connect the event handler to your frame either using the event table or dynamically using Connect() or Bind() function. Take a look at the samples which come with wxWidgets distro. You should find the good example there.

Comment: BTW, according to the tags, you are using the CodeBlocks. CoeBlocks has the built-in wxSmith GUI editor plugin. Are you using it or wxFormBuilder?